# How to check permissions of an ASP.NET Role

Tags: asp.net, security

how Ican use declarative security("[PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "")]) but I don't want to check role I need to check the permissions for that role?
scince I have roles and permissions for each role how I can use declarative security for permissions?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tie your Roles along with your Permissions table, you'll probably want to write your own class.  I haven't read this link, but see if the following [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172766(VS.80).aspx) helps at all ...

**EDIT:** Or, you could store the Permissions values within each user's [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs(VS.80).aspx), whether it be with one of the default providers or [one you've developed yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163457.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Roles don't have Permissions in asp.net ... they ARE the permissions.

Page.User.IsInRole("FileUploader")
Page.User.IsInRole("Administrator")

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx

Comment: if I have database that contain roles table and permissions table what I can do to check the permissions for user role?

Comment: idk, it's your code. Page_Load() { WafaasDB.GetPermissionsForRole("WafaasGirls") } ... but I would not do this in an attribute. .net has the concept of roles, not roles & permissions ... so you'll have to figure out how to roll you own I guess. But I would simplify and just use roles, going beyond that is too complicated imho